# Android 6 strips link from text with Html.fromHtml() method

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail, fromhtml

**What I want**

Open gmail with a certain text that contains anchors.

**What I expect**

I expected that text is shown in Gmail with a anchor to a website.

**Problem**

On Android 4.1.2 (and maybe al other android 4 devices) it works really well, but on Android 6 it doesn't work. It is showing the text of the anchor but not the anchor itself.

Like "a website" in plain text instead of a link.

**Code**

in strings.xml:

```
<string name="bring_a_friend_mail"><a href="http://google.nl">a website</a></string>
```

also tried with:

```
<string name="bring_a_friend_mail">
       <![CDATA[
          <a href="http://google.nl">a website</a>
       ]]>
    </string>
```

and in java code:

```
shareBodyMail = getString(R.string.bring_a_friend_mail);

sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(shareBodyMail));
```

**Solution**

Can someone help me to give some directions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SpannableString`

```
SpannableString s =new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(shareBodyMail));
        Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, s);
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work :( still get just the text without a link

Comment: try removing Html.fromFtml

Comment: thanks for helping, but that doesn't work either. just get "a website" without link. got  SpannableString s = new SpannableString(shareBodyMail);